# Why does Windows Defender detect compiled autoit executables as viruses?

Tags: windows, autoit, antivirus, false-positive, windows-defender

I have another issue not related to script or syntax
it a problem with the windows defender
I write a very very basic program. this

```
ProgressOn("Waiting", "Setup", "Loading")
 For $i = 0 To 50
     ProgressSet($i)
     Sleep(50)
 Next
```

but I don't know why is my Windows Defender detecting a virus in it?
it is just a loading bar and nothing more...

Comment: [link]( https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/34658-are-my-autoit-exes-really-infected/). In short: "the antivirus programs are to blame"

Comment: Can you guide me, how to fix it? I also address to Microsoft false positive more a month but not fix yet

Comment: According to the linked AutoIt forum, there is no fix because it's totally the Antivirus's fault. You can try the directive `#AutoIt3Wrapper_UseUpx=n`, but no guarantee that will work.

Comment: (just to be clear: there is nothing wrong with your script - it's about anything compiled with AutoIt)

Comment: I'm 100% sure, it just a loading bar. You can also try this code, and you will see, wd is detecting it. very awkward

Comment: as I said - it's not the script...

Comment: Did you ever try to sign your code with proper Certificate to have this particular problem solved ? I ask because each time when I compile my code and do not sign then always WindowsDefender mocking me about such things.

Comment: no sir, I did not try digital certificate ever. You can tell me or give me tutorial to how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's an antivirus issue and there's nothing you can REALLY do about it. It's not only Windows Defender. If you upload your compiled script to VirusTotal, you'll see that most major AV vendor detect it as malware.

Compiling with the 64-bit compiler will make your script less prone to false alarms, but popular AVs like Windows Defender will still detect it as malware.

I would recommend you to compile your script as .a3x and distribute it with the original AutoIt compiler.